# An alternative to "Old Wives' Tales" to avoid implying old women are likely to be wrong

Tags: phrase-requests

An *old wives' tale*, according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/old-wives-tale), is *a traditional belief, especially one which is incorrect*.

We might not always want to imply that married women, however ancient, are repositories of traditional erroneous views, so is there an alternative phrase carrying similar meaning?

Sometimes *folk wisdom* ([Collins again](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/folk-wisdom)) will do, but this doesn't carry the same suggestion of "probably wrong" or scepticism.  It works,  in my opinion, in the context of traditional cooking tips in [a question at cooking.se](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/115606/20413) (where I suggested it as an alternative), but I can't see it being a universal replacement.

Comment: It’s the “tales” part that lends the skepticism, so “folk tales” would be better than “folk wisdom”. You could use scare quotes around “wisdom” though.

Comment: Urban myth? Faulty assumption? Debunked tradition? Plain wrong?

Comment: @YosefBaskin at least some of those suggestions would be worth a vote as an answer

Comment: @ColleenV that's a good one too

Comment: Also see this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/226484/365490

Comment: You could also use **superstition**.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul "superstition" along with "myth" is a little dull, but could be used

Comment: @BenjaminHarman that may be true, but it doesn't help much to imply criticism of  old tales told by all women.

Answer (score 4):

The term **shibboleth** is used with this meaning.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shibboleth) defines this sense:

> *shibboleth*
>
> 1a: a word or saying used by adherents of a party, sect, or belief and
> usually regarded by others as empty of real meaning
>
> - *the old shibboleths come rolling off their lips* [Joseph Epstein]

and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shibboleth):

> *shibboleth* ...
>
> (3) a common saying or belief with little current meaning or truth.

Comment: About as good as you can get.  Others that keep closer to the original have to avoid not just ageism but also sexism and, for the matter of that, what I should call 'allotriophobia' (a hostile fear of difference and particularly of people that differ from the general mass.

Answer (score 4):

***[myth](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/myth)***

Any place you see the idiom "old wives' tale" used, you can insert "myth" into its place.

**[urban legend](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/urban-legend)**

If you're instead looking for another idiom for "old wives' tale," you can readily insert the idiom "urban legend" into its place. While "urban legend" tends to denote *newness* instead of *oldness*, what is considered *new* and what is considered *old* is relative and is highly subjective.

Comment: 'Urban legend' is what I was going to post.

Answer (score 2):

***Folklore***

From the [American Heritage Dictionary definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/folklore)

> a. A body of widely accepted but usually spurious notions about a place, group, or institution: *Rumors of their antics became part of the folklore of Hollywood.*
> b. A popular but unfounded belief.

You may have to rephrase to make it work in place of “old wives’ tale”, but it keeps the sense of oral traditions.